# How do i delete/update a doc with lucene?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am creating a [tagging system for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438000/how-do-i-implement-tag-searching-with-lucene/2442642#2442642)

I got the basics of adding a document to lucene but i can seem to figure out how to delete a document or update one when the user changes the tags of something. I found pages that say use the document index and i need to optimize before effect but how do i get the document index? Also i seen another that said to use IndexWriter to delete but i couldnt figure out how to do it with that either.

I am using C# asp.net and i dont have java install on that machine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What version of Lucene are you using? The IndexWriter class has an update method that lets you update (BTW an update under the hood is really a delete followed by an add). You will need to have some identifier (such as as document id) which lets you update. When you index the document, add a unique document identifier such as a URL, a counter etc. Then the "Term" will be the ID of the document you wish to update. For example using URL you can update thus:

```
IndexWriter writer = ...
writer.update(new Term("id","http://somedomain.org/somedoc.htm"), doc);
```

Comment: Incubating-Apache-Lucene.Net-2.0-004-11Mar07.bin.zip. So perhaps lucene 2.0.

Comment: Yikes, i just realized the date. I found an svn tag using Lucene.Net_2_9_1

Comment: Just so i am clear. Doc is the new document filled with the data i want. The term is the id of the old document i want to update/replace? -edit- update looks like a DeleteAdd. doc doesnt need to hold the same id or term as the older one.

Comment: yes to your first point.

Unsure what you mean by the 2nd, it is very advisable to have an id term for your doc (much like having a primary key for a db table).

Comment: Perfect, i just tested it. It does create a doc even if the term doesnt exist. My id will be the same id as the media or doc id (which is a PK in my db)

Answer (score 3):

You need an `IndexReader` to delete a document, I'm not sure about the .net version but the Java and C++ versions of the Lucene API have an `IndexModifier` class that hides the differences between `IndexReader` and `IndexWriter` classes and just uses the appropriate one as you call `addDocument()` and `removeDocument()`.

Also, there is no concept of updating a document in Lucene you have to remove it an them re-add it again. In order to do this you will need to make sure that every document has a unique stored id in the index.

Comment: great to know about updates. I dont see removeDocument nor IndexModifier (maybe .net is using an older version of lucene). I see a DeleteDocument in IndexReader. It accepts 'int docNum'. I have no idea what to do with it. Theres no docNum or docId in Document

Comment: the docnum is the enumerator key, for example 

IndexReader rdr = IndexReader.Open(@"Myindex");
int N = rdr.MaxDoc();
for(int n = 0; n< N; n++)
{
Document doc = rdr.Document(n);
//do something with this doc
}